# VB NET how to put encode charset in vb form and affiliated members

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm creating a visual basic translation system and this system takes from a INI file the new translation of the example form element:

```
 Private Sub SelectLanguage()
        '' PT BR LANGUAGE
        If ini.Sections("SetLanguages").Keys("Portuguese").Value = True Then
            'login
            Me.Label2.Text = ini.Sections("LoadingPT").Keys("Ptloading").Value
            login.Label2.Text = ini.Sections("LoginPT").Keys("Textpt1").Value
            login.Label3.Text = ini.Sections("LoginPT").Keys("Textpt2").Value
            login.Button1.Text = ini.Sections("LoginPT").Keys("Buttonpt1").Value 
End if 
End Sub
```

And if there were more languages ​​in the INI file he would get it I'm creating translations for portuguese brazil and for chinese and japanese but when he loads the text of the ini it doesn't show special UTF8 or ANSCII code characters

EXAMPLE:
 does not show Japanese characters

nor characters from katakana hiragana table

nor ç, Â á is í ã]%

these characters are simply replaced by an example question mark

Action or in Portuguese AÇÃO
will come ?????

the imported ini file is

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports MadMilkman.Ini
    Public Class Form1
        Dim ini As New IniFile()

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            ini.Load("C:\Myapp\config.ini")

      End Sub


    End Class
```

I would like if someone had a solution for the entire Form could change the character type to UTF8 or UNICODE

Exemple:

```
Form1.Charset = UTF8
```

or knew something similar I would like a light for my project
or knew something similar I would like a light for my project remembering my problem is in reading the file not in the recording and I use the dll

MadMilkman.Ini

to read the files

something similar also serves as an example:

```
login.Label2.Text = Encoding.UTF8(ini.Sections("LoginPT").Keys("Textpt1").Value)
```

I need to read the languages ​​Portuguese Chinese English.

If possible line breaks thank you

My Config.ini file:

```
[LoginPT]
Textpt1 = Acessar Conta
Textpt2 = Senha
Buttonpt1 = Entrar
Buttonpt2 = Nova Conta
Check1 = Manter-me conectado

[LoadingPT]
Ptloading = Carregando:

[SetLanguages]
Portuguese =True
English =False
Japonese =False
Chinese =False
```

thank you

Comment: .NET strings are UTF-16, not UTF-8, so you would need to handle this at the file boundary.  I suspect that you won't find any built-in .ini file handling that is Unicode-aware, since the format has basically been deprecated since ca. 20 years ago, so you would likely need to write your own .ini file handler that would know to read as UTF-8 instead of ASCII.  Unless you have a really good reason for doing this using .ini files, I'd recommend to work with the existing .NET localization machinery (resources in .resx files).

Comment: thanks for your reply and thank you for your interest. Well I chose ini because many programs still use today and I need a standard storage but creating one is not so difficult